# Less CSS engine refresh command to only one file

Tags: css, less

I have a page with the following html in the `<head>` section

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/css/shared/default.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/css/shared/shared.less" />
```

If you use Google Chrome you can open the inspector and see it load these files.  They are meant to be loaded only once however.

I need to dynamically load LESS files so I have a javascript function that does the following.

```
var cssurl  = "/css/"+device+"/404.less";
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/less";
link.href = cssurl;
less.sheets.push(link);

less.refresh();//load less file dynamically
```

When you look under the Google Chrome Inspector under the Network tab, a problem appears.

The problem is the **less.refresh()** loads not only the new less file I was pushing (404.less in my example) but it also loads the default.less and shared.less again (unnecessarily); I only want it to load the new 404.less file since shared and default have already been loaded.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it makes sense to recompile all code on `less.refresh();`. `less.refresh();` runs the complete compile process, which loads all less files from the DOM. The less compiler finds the Less code based on the `rel="stylesheet/less"` attribute.

Cause you are able to add an extra resource before `less.refresh();` you should also be able to remove them. You can remove resource already load by removing the `rel="stylesheet/less"` attribute before calling  `less.refresh();`.

Example code:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet/less"]');
[].forEach.call(matches, function(match) {
 match.setAttribute("rel","");
});
var cssurl  = "/css/"+device+"/404.less";
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/less";
link.href = cssurl;
less.sheets.push(link);
less.refresh();
```